# Record is creating with record id, not name

Tags: trigger, after-trigger

```
trigger VisitorChangedIntoPatient on Visitor__c (after insert) {

    List<Patient__c> pat = new List<Patient__c>();

    for(Visitor__c visitor : Trigger.New)
    {
         Patient__c p = new Patient__c();

        if(Visitor.Covid_19_Symtomp__c=='Fever;Dry Cough')
        {

            p.Name=visitor.Name+'SQC';
            p.IsInfected__c=TRUE;
        }
        pat.add(p);

    }

    insert pat;


}
```

[image: Patient record]

Comment: Is this record id of a patient__c record or a visitor__c record? Also, is there any other automation (Workflow/process builder running) on Patient__c which maybe changing the name to id?

Comment: After reading your comment, I have deleted all the process builder and workflow on the same object, but still record is creating with id not name. Please help.

Comment: Why would you delete that instead of deactivating it? Can you check answer by Pranay, that may work?

Comment: Yes, sorry, That was( delete) typo. I deactivated all of them and tried pranay solution. but it did not work

Comment: Thanks Manish for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Visitor.Covid_19_Symtomp__c=='Fever;Dry Cough'` does excact match . The first systmptom should be fever and second should be dry cough. If you change the order, the execution wont enter if-block.

instead use [contains](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000090NzIAI)

```
 if(Visitor.Covid_19_Symtomp__c.contains('Fever') && Visitor.Covid_19_Symtomp__c.contains'Dry Cough')
```

Comment: I just added your line as it is, but no change, record is creating with id not name.

Comment: Thanks Pranay. It worked.